# Office js Custom XML

Tags: javascript, xml, excel, office-js

I am trying to implement Custom XML parts feature in Office js.

While creating custom XML part in Excel, I am getting a GeneralException
while adding the XML part in workbook.

I am fetching data from excel having 5000 rows and 4 columns.

I am encoding the data using Base64 encoding and storing the data in a XML tag in the following format -

My encoded data.

Are there any size limitation while adding a custom XML part in the workbook ?Is there any specific behind this error?

Example:

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var xmlObj = "<data>My encoded data.</data>";
    var xmlPart = ctx.workbook.customXmlParts.add(xmlObj);
    return ctx.sync();
});
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the code you're using and the data you're encoding?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT - I am using the following code to add the XML object to the workbook.

Excel.run(function(ctx){
 var xmlObj = Here goes my XML object;
 var xmlPart = ctx.workbook.customXmlParts.add(xmlObj);
 return ctx.sync();
});

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT - I have tried to add the XML object without encoding, it is failing for the same threshold.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing this issue to our attention! I was able to repro the behavior on a blank workbook against excel.exe. It is due to a bug that we will try to fix in the nearest future. Sorry for the inconvenience. Please stay tuned for Excel updates.

Comment: A fix has been checked in. Builds 16.0.8714 or later should have it. Please try again once you get the update, and let us know how it works. Sorry about the inconvenience, and thank you for raising the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is no size limitation as such. I'd recommend the following:

1. Try with smaller number of rows.
2. Make sure the final XML is valid (you could use online validation tool to make sure there are no special characters, etc. that's giving the error). Ideally the API should tell you if the XML is invalid... but worth double-checking.
3. Is this happening only when you encode? Try using just regular string concatenation for the sake of testing.
   Please let us know where it fails in above tests.

Comment: We are trying to test the custom XML feature to check how it performs with large datasets. We have tried regular string concatenation but the XML object is invalid as it contains special characters.

If we try encoding, the resultant XML object is valid , but it throws a GeneralException error while adding it to the customXML part.

Comment: It is failing for the same threshold ,  1000 rows and 4 columns. Is this have anything to do with internal memory used by Excel ?

Comment: @ArupamSengupta, can you please confirm it works for small XML documents, but doesn't work for large ones? How many chars is the total length of the XML document you are trying to set?

Comment: @ArupamSengupta, one more question: are you using Excel Online or a standalone excel.exe?

Comment: @ZlatkoMichailov-MSFT - It works for small XML documents , is there any no. of characters restriction for creating custom XML object ?

Comment: @ZlatkoMichailov-MSFT - i am using standalone excel.exe.

Comment: @ArupamSengupta: The Custom XML Parts feature itself doesn't impose a size limit (other than the 2GB BSTR limit). I suspect you are hitting some other limit, e.g. JSOM request size, Excel xml part, or Excel workbook. That's why I asked whether you are hitting Excel Online or excel.exe - they have different workbook limits. Perhaps your workbook is already too big, and when you try to double its size, Excel complains. If you can give us more (numerical) information about your setup, we'll greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @ZlatkoMichailov-MSFT  -  I am able to solve the issue now, when we are creating the XML part, we are not putting any data in it. Once it is created , we are updating the XML content by encoding the data and adding it.

By using this approach, we are able to store 300K rows and 10 columns of data in the XML part.