# Office.js add Custom XML tag to TableColumn

Tags: excel, xml, office-js

I am working on a excel add-in and want to implement custom xml tags for `TableColumn`s as shown in an example below.

```
<x:tableColumn
    validationFormat = "{​​​​​
        "Some":"JSON",
        "Here":"pls"
     }​​​​​"
    id="1"
    name="Source Name"
    xr3:uid="{​​​​​1A9C800B-1243-42F5-9CF2-D87EAF95259D}​​​​​"
    xmlns:xr3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2016/revision3"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"
/>
```

I found how to access/set the `id` and the `name` tag, now i want to add a validationFormat tag with a (json)string as value and i cannot find out how.
What i did find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46669356/office-js-custom-xml) question but it adds custom xml on a top level as far as i can see and cannot be used to set a tag to a `TableColumn`.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for your question, would you please share us the gist or sample code that we can repro locally? thanks

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. This is part of the open source repo found here: (https://github.com/nfdi4plants/Swate) We are using F# Fable to access office.js. Here (https://github.com/nfdi4plants/Swate/blob/developer/src/Client/OfficeInterop.fs#L90) is a example how we access a TableColumn.Name and at this point we would like to add custom Xml tags as shown in the main question to the TableColumn.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, Unfortunately, we do not support to add XML to TableColumn, Current we support to add custom XML by context.workbook.customXmlParts.